# Installation Problem

Tags: installation, 12.04, hard-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 in my laptop, I have experienced a few problems after my installation however. Firstly when I restart my computer I am not presented with the option to run Ubuntu, it just goes straight into running Windows. Secondly my hard-drive is partitioned into two, C and D, Windows is installed on C and Ubuntu got installed on D. Lastly whenever I want to run Ubuntu I have to insert the USB I used to install Ubuntu with, restart the laptop, press F12 for boot options and select the USB for me to be able to run Ubuntu, after this I can remove the USB and Ubuntu will run fine until I restart which will require me to use the USB again. I should mention that I don't know much about computers. How do I solve this problem I want to be presented with the option to run Ubuntu when I reboot and also want to install Ubuntu in C.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run 2 systems you should have 4 partitions: one for windows, one for Ubuntu, one as a Swap area and one for your documents. That should keep them apart. It should work, because Ubuntu installs it's boot loader over the old one. Are you sure that you [installed](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installing) it correctly.If yes, you should change your boot loader to [GNU GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB). It detects all kinds of operating systems. It should do the trick for you. But research about GRUB before you try anything, because you could not be able to restore your windows boot loader after applying it. Good luck.